# SQL Server 2000 - How to remove the hidden characters in the column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to remove a hidden characters from a `varchar` column, these hidden characters (i.e. period, space) was taken from a scanned bar code and it is not visible in the result set once query was executed. I have tried to use below script but it failed to remove the hidden characters(see attached screenshot for reference.)

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
SELECT Replace(Replace(LTrim(RTrim(mycolumn)), '.', ''), ' ', '')
FROM MyTable 
WHERE serialno = '123456789'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing that has worked for me is to select the column with the special characters, then paste the data into notepad++ then turn on View>Show Symbol>Show All Characters. Then I could copy the special characters from Notepad++ into the second argument of the REPLACE() function in SQL.

Comment: I have tried to do this but unfortunately it did not work. Data was copied to Notepad++ and turned on the Show All Characters, the GS with black background color(like on the screenshot above) did not change.

Comment: Try putting CHAR(29) in the second argument of the REPLACE() function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_separator#Field_separators

Comment: Yes CHAR(29) is the problem. I've found out using this script : SELECT ASCII(RIGHT(Column,2)) FROM MyTable.